# Combination of a discrete and a continuous Markov Chain in a MCMC

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, markov-process, discrete-time, continuous-time

Recently, I've been questioning myself on the possibility of combining a **discrete update** and a **continuous update** on a single MCMC. [Stephens (2000)](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-statistics/volume-28/issue-1/Bayesian-analysis-of-mixture-models-with-an-unknown-number-of/10.1214/aos/1016120364.full) in Algorithm 3.2 runs the process for a fixed amount of time and then use this result to update the rest while [Mohammadi and Wit (2015)](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bayesian-analysis/volume-10/issue-1/Bayesian-Structure-Learning-in-Sparse-Gaussian-Graphical-Models/10.1214/14-BA889.full) use a continuous update on one "parameter" and a discrete update on the other. Which is the correct way to go and why? I can't find any theoretical literature about it but I find it easier to discretize the continuous chain.

Comment: Stephens (2000) does not mix a discrete and a continuous Markov chain, but rather simulates a continuous-time jump process where the duration in one state is connected with the target distribution. Just like the more general PDMP algorithms.

Comment: I was not aware of PDMP algorithms and certainly will have a look on those. I understand that Stephens does not actually mix the discrete and continuous chains which is why i was wondering if there is some work or some theory about it.